# Windows 7 ultimate is not installing

Tags: windows-7

I have a strange night. I bought a used lenovo t410. It had ubuntu on it. I formatted the hard drive to ntfs and made a bootable usb flash drive. Booted it and the windows installer came up and it started installing and after a couple of minutes it needed to restart itself. After restarting....I was nowhere. I just asked me again if I want to install a fresh copy of Windows or repair it. I tried again...nothing happened. It seems like it took 7gb of space.I made a new flash drive with another windows 7 and it did the same thing...Any suggestions what might be the issue ?

Comment: Perhaps some piece of hardware on it is faulty. You could run some boot up tools to make sure components are fine

Comment: I was wondering if installing a 32bit windows would solve the problem. I have 6 months warranty,so I can return it if I want to. What tools would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When first reboot is about to occur remove USB bootable device and see if it will continue the installment.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)